# How to create individual listener for each marker in list

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a list of coordinates by which I set markers on my map. Markers appear on the map only at magnification less than 12. I want to make that when I click on the marker, some function is executed, and it is executed only one time.

Here's how it happened now:

```
for (let i = 0; i < locationsCoordinates.length; i++) {
    const bridge = locationsCoordinates[i];
    markers.push( new google.maps.Marker({
        position: bridge[1],
        title: bridge[0],
        map,
        icon: 'img/bridges.png',
        clickable: true,
    }));
}

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    let zoom = map.getZoom();
    if (zoom < 12) {
        for (let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            markers[i].setVisible(false);
            markers[i].addListener("click", function (event) {
                test +=1;
            });
            }
        }
     else {
        for (let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            markers[i].setVisible(true);
        }
    }
})
```

**The problem is that with code like this, the function runs multiple times when you click on any marker.**
Please help me fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [addListenerOnce](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/event#event.addListenerOnce) and refactor your code a bit. Something like this

```
var locationsCoordinates = [{lat: 12.84, lng: 122.89}, {lat: 12.80, lng: 122.93}, {lat: 12.74, lng: 122.85}];

var markers = [];

for (let i = 0; i < locationsCoordinates.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: locationsCoordinates[i],
        map
    });
    
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(marker, "click", () => {
        console.log("marker", i, "clicked");
    });
    
    markers.push(marker);
}

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    let zoom = map.getZoom();
    if (zoom < 12) {
        for (let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            markers[i].setVisible(false);
        }
    } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            markers[i].setVisible(true);
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Related question: [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

Add the listeners to the markers as in the related example, when you create the markers. Not in the `zoom_changed` event listener on the map.

Not sure why you are adding the listener when the marker is hidden (`.setVisible(false)` case), not when it is shown, but if you add the listener to the marker when the marker is created, you won't need to do anything special.

The related question uses function closure to associate the marker with its `InfoWindow` contents (or whatever you want to do when the marker is clicked), the code below uses the `let` keyword, which is the modern solution to that issue, but function closer can be used as well, particularly if you need to support older browsers.

```
  for (let i = 0; i < locationsCoordinates.length; i++) {
    const bridge = locationsCoordinates[i];
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: bridge[1],
      title: bridge[0],
      map,
      icon: 'img/bridges.png',
      clickable: true,
    });
    markers.push(marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
      infowindow.setContent(locationsCoordinates[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
      test += 1;
    });
  }
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    let zoom = map.getZoom();
    if (zoom < 12) {
      for (let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setVisible(false);
      }
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setVisible(true);
      }
    }
  })
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/a35q2fLx/4/)

**code snippet:**

```js
// The following example creates markers to indicate beaches near
// Sydney, NSW, Australia. 
let markers = [];
let test = 0;

function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: {
      lat: -33.9,
      lng: 151.2
    },
  });
  let infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  // Adds markers to the map.
  for (let i = 0; i < locationsCoordinates.length; i++) {
    const bridge = locationsCoordinates[i];
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: bridge[1],
      title: bridge[0],
      map,
      clickable: true,
    });
    markers.push(marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
      infowindow.setContent(locationsCoordinates[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
      test += 1;
      console.log("open infowindow:" + this.getTitle() + " test=" + test);
    });
  }
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    let zoom = map.getZoom();
    if (zoom < 12) {
      infowindow.close();
      for (let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setVisible(false);
      }
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setVisible(true);
      }
    }
  })
}
// Data for the markers consisting of a name and a LatLng.
const locationsCoordinates = [
  ["Bondi Beach", {
    lat: -33.890542,
    lng: 151.274856
  }],
  ["Coogee Beach", {
    lat: -33.923036,
    lng: 151.259052
  }],
  ["Cronulla Beach", {
    lat: -34.028249,
    lng: 151.157507
  }],
  ["Manly Beach", {
    lat: -33.80010128657071,
    lng: 151.28747820854187
  }],
  ["Maroubra Beach", {
    lat: -33.950198,
    lng: 151.259302
  }],
];
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Complex Marker Icons</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly" defer></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```